# does FPGA reset automatically after programmed?

Tags: fpga, reset, xilinx, vivado

I am working on FPGA projects, and just got one question right now.

When updating a bitstream on FPGA board, does it automatically reset all flip flop inside FPGA? When designing FPGA with Vivado, there is a reset external port which seems like an port the user must toggle to reset the FPGA.

If an initial FPGA programming process resets all flip flop automatically why would we need an external reset port?

Comment: The Global Set/Reset (GSR) signal is asserted during configuration to reset and re-initialize all the BRAMs and Flip-Flops. Where is this `reset external port`? If it is in your design, it can be used to reset the design without re-configuring..!! Is that what you mean? Check [link](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug470_7Series_Config.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Do I need to reset my FPGA design after startup?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227945/do-i-need-to-reset-my-fpga-design-after-startup)

Comment: When using vivado design tools, I used clocing wizard, and it gave me an reset external port and default sysclk 300mhz.

Comment: Would it be okay to assume that the FPGA initializes the FPGA BRAM and all cells inside after programming a device with the bitstream? Then there is no need to use reset signal to FPGA system.

Answer (score 0):

All the registers and BRAM cells in the FPGA are initialized during configuration, so you may not need an additional reset signal if that is all you are using in the FPGA.

Some of the hard logic components in an FPGA may need a reset, especially if you have multiple clocks.

FPGAs such as Zynq include a processor/IO complex that is not reset when the attached programmable logic is reconfigured.

Protocol implementations such as PCIE may need to reset to synchronize with their peers. It's convenient and sometimes necessary to use a reset signal in these cases rather than reprogramming the FPGA.

Comment: I am pretty sure not all registers will be reset, at least on the zynq architecture, after sending the bitstream to the fpga. When I start Linux on my Zynq the registers (clocks for example) are set in the fsbl and can manually be changed (be careful). But reading the registers some are reset to zero (DMA, ...) but not all, depending where they are physically and how they are initiated.

Comment: My statement referred to all registers in the programmable logic. On Zynq, the source clocks are controlled from registers in the processor complex and are not reset when the programmable logic is configured.